# How to name a linked column in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

In EF version 6.2, I have a Student and Scholarship table.
I have a class:

```
 public class SS2
{
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SS2ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("StudentId", Order = 2)]
    public Student StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("ScholarshipId", Order = 3)]
    public Scholarship ScholarshipId { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting the name of the SS2 table to have the column names StudentId and ScholarshipId. Instead they are named "StudentId_StudentId" and "ScholarshipId_ScholarshipId" after running update-database.

Does anyone know why the column name is not being respected on the data annotation? Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForeignKeyAttribute for this:

```
[Required]
[Column(Order = 2)]
[ForeignKey("StudentId")]
public Student StudentId { get; set; }
```